# How can I make a image scrollbar in android studio like the ones on sites?

Tags: android, xml, image, user-interface, scrollbar

I want to make a scrollbar with a tiny little buttons on the bottom like the one on the images. what should I do?

[first scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHdZk.png)

[second scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J30O.png)

Comment: Sliding motion.

Comment: I want sth like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ronaldsmartin/Material-ViewPagerIndicator/assets/screenshots/1.0.0/capture-v1.0.0.gif

Answer (score 3):

you can use viewpager for that and for showing the dots you can make your custom drawable. and you can give height and width to main view according to your requirement, then it will work

Comment: I want sth like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ronaldsmartin/Material-ViewPagerIndicator/assets/screenshots/1.0.0/capture-v1.0.0.gif

Answer (score 0):

You might thinking of using ViewPager and a ViewPagerIndicator.